# Permission is not letting Service interact with mounted virtual folder / drive

Tags: windows, service, permissions

I'm mounting a folder to a virtual disk like this (I'm on Windows XP):

```
subst z: c:\virtual_disk
```

This works perfectly okay for one thing, I have a Service (created with C++ / CreateService(...) ) running and it can write files to c:\virtual_disk but not to z:\

I'm using classic fopen, fwrite etc.

I have, I think, narrowed down the problem to some sort of permission problem, I'm not sure though.
The service runs on the  "localSystem" account and the folder is mounted by me using an administrator account.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping is per user. If you mapped Z using your own account, it won't catch for the local system account. You can either run the service under your own account, or have it do its own mapping.

Comment: As I can't do the mapping myself (it's part of a bigger project), how can I run a service from the current account? I have tried a lot of settings but it invariably ends up on 'localSystem'.

Comment: Open the services console, go to your service's properties, then the log on tab, and choose the "This account" option, where you can enter your own credentials. I've never dealt with installers, but I assume any decent installer can do that too, if you don't want to always do this manually.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, but IIRC, for a given user, mapping done with restricted permissions are not going to apply when operating with elevated permissions ("run as administrator") and vice versa. Services run with elevated permissions, so if you've done the mapping with limited permissions (default when UAC is on), try running cmd with "run as administrator", remap the drive and see if the problem remains.