# Map drives with subst on Windows Server 2012

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012, subst

I have configure Windows Sever 2012 as build machine for Visual Studio solutions for the first time.
On the machine the UAC is set to Minimum and I’m using subst to map drives and use them during the build.
The problem is that if I map the drive with subst using CMD > Run as administrator I don’t see the subst drive on Windows explorer and if I don’t use Run as administrator Visual Studio failed to run some post build action like .dll registration.

Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: This is normal, you're executing `subst` from an elevated command prompt, so the mappings it makes are only visible from other elevated processes. If you don't want this to be the case, then run `subst` from a *non-elevated* command prompt. Mapping with `subst` is *always* per-user!

Comment: Related question asked on a more appropriate site: http://superuser.com/questions/550205/unable-to-unmount-subst-drive. Other quasi-duplicates on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605783/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715025/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182329/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671677/, etc.

Comment: On Win 7 machine I ran subst from elevated command prompt and I can access the drive for windows explorer but it doesn't seems to be the case on Server 2012, also I know I can subst from a non-elevated command prompt but than as I wrote Visual Studio failed to run some post build actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although UAC was set to Minimum only after I have updated the registry as explained here:

[Windows Server 2012: Deactivating UAC](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13953.windows-server-2012-deactivating-uac.aspx)

Then I could use subst to map the drives from a non-elevated command prompt and VisualStudio successfully run post build actions even if I didn’t run it with Run as Administrator.